# using the setter method ["set()"] under HttpParams

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to convert the following method to Angular 7.
The data doesn't set to the params. can someone point me out why doesn't it works? It says

> error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'params'.

```
updateParamsWithAuth(params: HttpParams, appKey: string, field: string) {
let token;
if (appKey && appKey.length > 0) {
  token = this.getAccessTokenFromSession();

} else {
  token = this.getRSTokenFromSession();
  if (field === this.FIELD_ACCESS_TOKEN) {
    field = this.FIELD_RS_TOKEN;
  }
}

// params.set(field, token);
let params = new HttpParams().set(field, token);

return params;
}
```

Comment: rename `let params` to something else

Comment: you have already passed a parameter named `params` to the method and trying to define another parameter named `params` in the method. This might cause the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `params` as a parameter to  `updateParamsWithAuth` function and again inside function declaring params variable again. 
Just use,

```
params = new HttpParams().set(field, token);
```

or declare it with deferent identifier.

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams().set(field, token);
```

Answer (score 0):

params is a parameter of your method and you declared another variable named params before return and that is the issue.

cahnge this `let params = new HttpParams().set(field, token);`

to this `params = new HttpParams().set(field, token);`

> But my question is why you need to reinitialize it here?  If you
>   initialize it here again there is no point to pass it as a parameter
>   of that method, isn't it?

You already have params inside the method, so, I think no need to initialize it again.

If you don't want the value of params that comes to you as a parameter better remove that parameter from that method as you are initializing a new HttpParams inside the method. Or else use the existing params.

From my point the code should be like this -

```
updateParamsWithAuth(params: HttpParams, appKey: string, field: string) {
    let token;
    if (appKey && appKey.length > 0) {
      token = this.getAccessTokenFromSession();

    } else {
      token = this.getRSTokenFromSession();
      if (field === this.FIELD_ACCESS_TOKEN) {
        field = this.FIELD_RS_TOKEN;
      }
    }

    params = params.set(field, token);

    return params;
}
```